# How to display the start date one day ahead with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

The select date seem to be empty when I added `startDate: '+1d'` into the javascript. Otherwise, it is just displaying today's date. I need it to display one day ahead and in some situations, two days ahead as well.

Javascript below:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true, 
    todayHighlight: false,
    startDate:'+1d',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
}).datepicker('update', new Date());
```

HTML Code below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Date Range</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly id="start"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="datepicker2" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly id="end"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js for this type of date/time manipulation

```
var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').format('DD/M/YYYY');
```

outputs

03/11/2016

see jsbin:
here is the full working jsfiddle: https://jsbin.com/haxamaxaqe/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker('setDate', "+1d");
```